# How to Debug PHP side in an AIR application?

Tags: php, apache-flex, debugging, air, desktop-application

I have an AIR application which uses RemoteObject to comunicate with remote services in PHP (using Zend AMF).

The application works great, but I can't debug the PHP side (the Flex debugger works fine, the PHP side is the problem).

I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP, when I write a Web Application (not AIR), I can choose to debug the application as "Web (PHP) Application", and the breakpoints in the PHP side are working as expected.

But I can't see any similar option for Desktop Applications (AIR).

Does somebody know if it's possible (and how) to debug the PHP side in an AIR application?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like xdebug, or PHPStorm.  Start a debug session, capture the service id (available in the GUI interface for both) and send an additional header on all requests from your AIR app to include XDEBUG_SESSION: .

Comment: Do you know how to do the same with Zend Debugger? or this is possible only with xdebug?

Answer (score 0):

the debuging process actually the same. run your amf service in debug mode, just put breakpoint anywhere you like. whenever air application doing a service call, then the process will automatically stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: that is not working to me obviously. And I think it's not so "simple" how you are guessing, why Adobe would make a different option for debugging with PHP then (the problem is that this option is only available for Web and Mobile Application, not Desktop).

Comment: so strange if it is work with flex and didn't work with air, because the calling mechanism is actually very the same. it just an http request. but have you test your service via the service console? it is (service console) a flex so it will work right? and in the same time (and reference the same url) make a call from the air, let me know what happen.

Comment: No, how I said, I think you are oversimplifying the problem, why Adobe would make two special options (Debug Web (PHP) and Debug Mobile (PHP) applications) if you don't need to do any extra? and why that option is not in Desktop application? I think is not the same http request, when you use a browser you send a lot of extra data, query strings, cookies, etc, and I think Zend Debugger uses that. The AIR app is not sending that, I have added de query string to my endpoint (url to gateway) but it didn't work. Are you debugging PHP in AIR apps?

Comment: sorry i don't use PHP, but .Net (fluorine) service, i was frequently debug my server side code using AIR application. even today i double check to make sure whether it is caused by the new air environment, but it working fine..